# Including JSP file within another JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, wizard

I'm writing a wizard for creating a user in my application with Spring MVC. At each step the controller will set session attributes for the completed wizard fields.

I want the wizard to look the same regardless of which page it's on, except for each page's fields, obviously. For example, menus and links at the top of the page and buttons at the bottom should remain the same.

I have the following JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Create a new User</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>User Creation Wizard</h1>
        Step <c:out value = "${pageNum}"/>/<c:out value = "${pageMax}"/>

        <form action="" method="POST">
            <jsp:include page="userform${pageView}.jsp"/>

            <input name = "currentPage" type = "hidden" value = "${pageNum}"/>
            <c:if test = "${pageNum > 1}">
                <input name = "prev" type = "submit" value = "Previous" />
            </c:if>

            <c:if test = "${pageNum < pageMax}">
                <input name = "next" type = "submit" value = "Next" />
            </c:if>

            <c:if test = "${pageNum == pageMax}">
                <input name = "submit" type = "submit" value = "Finish" />
            </c:if>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the jsp I'm including, do I need to remove the `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags? The above code is based on [this example](http://gablog.eu/online/node/89.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd need to remove the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags from the included JSP file. As they'd already be present in the including file keeping them would result in invalid HTML.

Only the content that you want to vary would be in the JSP file you're including. Everything else, including the necessary `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, would be in the JSP file that does the including.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you want to use the `<c:if>` tags, for example, inside the JSP you're including, you'll need the taglib directive in that JSP as well.